# com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) @org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeRenderChart

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am trying to add a 'Chart' (HighCharts-Angular Gauge) to a Flow Panel.
While adding I getting the below exception

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) @org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeRenderChart(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;ZZLcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)([string: 'Chart', JavaScript object(15907), bool: false, bool: false, JavaScript object(15932), JavaScript object(15933), JavaScript object(15934), JavaScript object(15924), JavaScript object(15928), JavaScript object(15923), JavaScript object(15926), JavaScript object(15927), JavaScript object(15930), JavaScript object(15931)]): 
    b is undefined  at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)  at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionEvent.fire(SelectionEvent.java:43)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.fireSuggestionEvent(SuggestBox.java:1166)   at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.setNewSelection(SuggestBox.java:1190)   at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.access$7(SuggestBox.java:1185)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox$2.onSuggestionSelected(SuggestBox.java:683)     at 


Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeRenderChart(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;ZZLcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)([string: 'Chart', JavaScript object(15907), bool: false, bool: false, JavaScript object(15932), JavaScript object(15933), JavaScript object(15934), JavaScript object(15924), JavaScript object(15928), JavaScript object(15923), JavaScript object(15926), JavaScript object(15927), JavaScript object(15930), JavaScript object(15931)]): b is undefined    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    at
        .
        .
```

I have added imports like highcharts.js , highcharts-more.js and exporting.js
in my GWT.html

But still it is giving an exception.
Please help.

Hi Ignacio,

Thanks for the reply.
I have debugged it, in the BaseChart class provided by highcharts I found the **b**, which is **boolean**

This is the line where it is causing the exception in BaseChart class,

```
chart = nativeRenderChart(
            getChartTypeName(),
            createNativeOptions(),
            toolTip != null && toolTip.getToolTipFormatter() != null,
            legend != null && legend.getLabelsFormatter() != null,
            chartEventHandlers.getJavaScriptObject(),
            seriesEventHandlers.getJavaScriptObject(),
            pointEventHandlers.getJavaScriptObject(),
            xAxisEventHandlers.getJavaScriptObject(),
            yAxisEventHandlers.getJavaScriptObject(),
            xAxisLabelFormatters.getJavaScriptObject(),
            yAxisLabelFormatters.getJavaScriptObject(),
            yAxisStackLabelFormatters.getJavaScriptObject(),
            plotOptionsLabelFormatters.getJavaScriptObject(),
            seriesLabelFormatters.getJavaScriptObject()
        );
```

Took a javascript from 
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/EjRLw/

and added the following
Pane,
YAxis (tick postion,width,color)
GaugePlotOptions(color,linewidth,stacking),
Series(Points),
ToolTip(ValueSuffix)

I am setting Everything.
I verified all 14 objects set to 'nativeRenderChart' method are not null.

Still getting same exception!!!!
No clue at all :( !!!
Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this.
The issue was with the below code,

```
GaugePlotOptions plotOptions = new GaugePlotOptions();
//  plotOptions.setStacking( Stacking.NORMAL ); <<--- CULPRIT
```

Set 'Stacking' in 'GaugePlotOptions' was causing the exception.
Once it is removed Chart appeared in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

This is the NullPointerException equivalent for JS. You probably miss some chart config and it ends up failing. To see exactly what is happening the recommended strategy is to debug your project (code-server) and use the chrome dev-tools "pause on caught exceptions". This will stop exactly at this NPE and you should see what is missing and what means `b`. You must see all the source codes in chrome; Java, JSNI or dependant JS libs.

Comment: Thank you ,
seriesLabelFormatters.getJavaScriptObject() is returning as false and b is boolean

Almost everything I m setting as mentioned above,
Are there any mandatory fields which I am not setting?